# Simple python iteration exercise..stuck with try and except

Tags: python

Write a program which repeatedly reads numbers until the user enters "done". Once "done" is entered, print out the total, count, and average of the numbers. If the user enters anything other than a number, detect their mistake using try and except and print an error message and skip to the next number.

This is what I have.

```
total = 0
count = 0
average = 0
while True:
    number = input("Enter a number:")
    if number == "done":
        break
    try:
        total += numbers
        count += 1
        average = total / len(number)
    except:
        print ("Invalid input")
    continue
print (total, count, average)
```

When I run this, I always get invalid input for some reason. My except part must be wrong.

EDIT:
This is what I have now and it works. I do need, however, try and except, for non numbers.

```
total = 0
count = 0
average = 0
while True:
    number = input("Enter a number:")
    if number == "done":
        break
    total += float(number)
    count += 1
    average = total / count
print (total, count, average)
```

I think I got it?!?!

```
total = 0
count = 0
average = 0
while True:
    number = input("Enter a number:")
    try:
        if number == "done":
            break
        total += float(number)
        count += 1
        average = total / count
    except:
        print ("Invalid input")
print ("total:", total, "count:", count, "average:", average)
```

Should I panic if this took me like an hour?
This isn't my first programming language but it's been a while.

Comment: Is this python 2 or python 3?

Comment: What is the exception you want to catch in the except block? Remove the try-except and see, what error you really get.

Comment: Hey guys. This is Python 3. @Daniel, I'll try that now. I'm trying to catch if it's not entering numbers.

Comment: Debugging step 1: Remove `try ... except` to see the exception that's thrown. Debugging complete.

Comment: Hi. I updated what I have now. It's working but I still need try and except.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but thought I'd throw my 2-cents in there (since I myself many years later am using the same examples to learn). You could try:

```
values=[]
while True: 
    A=input('Please type in a number.\n')
    if A == 'done':
        break
    try:
        B=int(A)
        values.append(B)
    except:
        print ('Invalid input')

total=sum(values)
average=total/(len(values))
print (total, len(values), average)
```

I find this a tad cleaner (and personally easier to follow).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you try to use your input:

```
try:
    total += numbers
```

First, there is no value **numbers**; your variable is singular, not plural.  Second, you have to convert the text input to a number.  Try this:

```
try:
    total += int(number)
```

Comment: Yeah, I got that. :)

Comment: Good.  The original code will raise an exception every time: attempt to use a variable's value before initialization.  You still have a problem with counting the quantity of input, but that's another issue.

Comment: I think I got the entire thing.

Answer (score 0):

It's because there is no len(number) when number is an int. len is for finding the length of lists/arrays. you can test this for yourself by commenting out the try/except/continue. I think the code below is more what you are after?

```
total = 0
count = 0
average = 0
while True:
    number = input("Enter a number:")
    if number == "done":
        break
    try:
        total += number
        count += 1
        average = total / count
    except:
        print ("Invalid input")
    continue
print (total, count, average)
```

note there are still some issues. for example you literally have to type "done" in the input box in order to not get an error, but this fixes your initial problem because you had len(number) instead of count in your average. also note that you had total += numbers. when your variable is number not numbers. be careful with your variable names/usage.

Comment: I  think I got it.

Answer (score 0):

A solution...

```
total = 0
count = 0
average = 0
while True:
    number = input("Enter a number:")
    if number == "done":
        break
    else:
        try:
            total += int(number)
            count += 1
            average = total / count
        except ValueError as ex:
            print ("Invalid input")
            print('"%s" cannot be converted to an int: %s' % (number, ex))
print (total, count, average)
```

Problems with your code:

- total+=numbers # *numbers* don't exist; is *number*
- len(number) # *number* is a string. for the average you need count
- if is not ***done***, else process it
- Use try ... except ValueError to catch problem when convert the *number* to int.
- Also, you can use try ... except ValueError as ex to get an error message more comprehensible.

Comment: Hi. Can you check what I wrote too? I think it's right.

Comment: Is OK. Don't panic. Never lose heart!

Answer (score 0):

So, after several attempts, I got the solution

```
num = 0
count = 0
total = 0
average = 0
while True:
    num = input('Enter a number: ')
    if num == "done":
        break
    try:
        float(num)
    except:
        continue
    total = total + float(num)
    count = count + 1
    average = total / count
 print(total, count, average)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Old problem with Update solutions

```
num = 0
total = 0.0
while True:
number = input("Enter a number")
if number == 'done':
    break
try :
    num1 = float(number)
except:
    print('Invailed Input')
    continue
num = num+1
total = total + num1
print ('all done')
print (total,num,total/num)
```

[Write and Run picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GO2hZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Covers all error and a few more things. Even rounds the results to two decimal places.

```
count = 0
total = 0
average = 0
print()
print('Enter integers and type "done" when finished.')
print('Results are rounded to two decimals.')
while True:
    inp = input("Enter a number: ")

    try:
        if count >= 2 and inp == 'done': #only breaks if more than two integers are entered
            break
        count = count + 1
        total += float(inp)
        average = total / count
    except:
        if count <=1 and inp == 'done':
            print('Enter at least 2 integers.')
        else:
            print('Bad input')
        count = count - 1

print()
print('Done!')
print('Count: ' , count, 'Total: ' , round(total, 2), 'Average: ' , round(average, 2))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
sum = 0
count = 0

loopControl = True
while loopControl:
    try:
        num = input('Enter a number: ')
        if num != 'done':
            num = int(num)
            sum += num
            count += 1
        else:
            loopControl = False
    except:
        print('Invalid input')

print(sum, count, sum / count)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**